# Check network connection in libGDX

Tags: java, android, networking, libgdx

I would like to check network connection with use of `libGDX` and tried to use code below.

```
HttpRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new HttpRequestBuilder();
Net.HttpRequest httpRequest = requestBuilder.newRequest().method(Net.HttpMethods.GET).url("https://api.vk.com/").build();

Net.HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener = new httpResponseListener() {
    public void handleHttpResponse (Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
        HttpStatus status = httpResponse.getStatus();
        if (status.getStatusCode() >= 200 && status.getStatusCode() < 300) {
            // it was successful
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}

Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, httpResponseListener);
```

It has several errors, like `Gdx.net` doesn't have `sendHttpRequest()` function now. How should I correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdx.net` has got `sendHttpRequest()` method - it seems that you are using not proper `HttpRequest` instance (why this `Net...` is starting with uppercase?)

A proper minimal example of how to use `Gdx.net` is beneath - I have also added a comments where it was necessary

```
    public class HttpManager implements HttpResponseListener 
    {   
        public HttpState state;
        private String result;
        private byte[] byteResult;

        HttpRequest request;

        public HttpManager()
        {
            request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setMethod(Net.HttpMethods.GET); //or POST
            request.setContent(""); //you can put here some PUT/GET content
            request.setUrl(url);
            Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) 
        {
            if( httpResponse.getStatus().getStatusCode() != 200 )
            {
                //ERROR
                float errorCode = httpResponse.getStatus().getStatusCode();
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] byteResult = httpResponse.getResult(); //you can also get result as String by using httpResponse.getResultAsString();
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is `net` only in uppercase: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html

Comment: `Net` is interface due to documentation when `Gdx.net` is default libGDX module to deal with internet requests - provided example should be running properly so try it yourself